# updating angular model with bootstrap carousel

Tags: angularjs, web, angular-ui-bootstrap

i'm working on an angular web app and i'm stuck in a part of it.i'm trying to update an angular model by choosing an item in a bootstrap carousel.i mean that if i select an image from the bootstrap carousel, the image's link will be put in the form used to update the model.is it possible to do it?this is the code i'm trying to make working

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="Interaction_Ctrl">
    <form>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Image URL:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="url" placeholder="http://reelyactive.com/images/barnowl.jpg" ng-model="person.image" ng-change='change()' class="form-control" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <carousel>
                    <slide ng-repeat="slide  in slides" active="slide.active" ng-model="person.image" ng-change='change()'>
                        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="height:100px; margin:auto">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                             <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>

                            <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
                    </slide >
                </carousel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>
```

```js
var mymodule = angular.module("jsonerator", ['ui.bootstrap']);


mymodule.controller("Interaction_Ctrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.slides = [];
    $scope.slides.push({
        text: 'barnowl',
        image: 'http://reelyactive.com/images/barnowl.jpg'
    });
    $scope.slides.push({
        text: 'barnacles',
        image: 'http://reelyactive.com/images/barnacles.jpg'
    });
    $scope.slides.push({
        text: 'barterer',
        image: 'http://reelyactive.com/images/barterer.jpg'
    });
    $scope.slides.push({
        text: 'chickadee',
        image: 'http://reelyactive.com/images/chickadee.jpg'
    });
    $scope.slides.push({
        text: 'starling',
        image: 'http://reelyactive.com/images/starling.jpg'
    });

function changeKeyValue() {
    for(var key in $scope.person) {
      if($scope.person.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if(!$scope.person[key].length) {
          delete $scope.person_ld["@graph"][0]["schema:" + key];
        } 
        else {
          $scope.person_ld["@graph"][0]["schema:" + key] = $scope.person[key];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  $scope.change = function() {
    changeKeyValue();
  }
});

});
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you are trying to update `ng-model="person.image"` with value from `ng-src="{{slide.image}}"` when clicking the respective carousel image?

Comment: exactly,this is what i'm trying to do

Comment: Could you please show the code for the `change()` method being executed within `ng-change='change()'`?

Comment: i updated the javascript file and now,you can see the change method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place the `input url` element somewhere within the `ng-repeat`, the input will update as the slides change. Right now the issue is the scope `{{slide.image}}` is within each `<scope>` element, so the input does cannot utilize the model attribute.

```
<carousel>
    <slide ng-repeat="slide  in slides" active="slide.active" ng-model="person.image">
        <input type="url" placeholder="http://reelyactive.com/images/barnowl.jpg" ng-model="person.image" class="form-control" />
        <br>
        <br>            
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="height:100px; margin:auto">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>

        <p>{{slide.text}}</p>                
    </slide >
</carousel>
```

You can adjust CSS or add additional `<br/>` to separate as needed. Plunker below. Let me know if that helps.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Kd23U1ercuqc2ACpQEZH?p=preview